# Tomcat не воспринимает plain old java

Tags: java-ee, java, tomcat

[Вот так расположены файлы (начиная с webapps)](http://db.tt/VPcbuCRx)

[Вот логи](http://db.tt/e3tXxV6C)

При попытке попасть на localhost/select.do возвращает 404, хотя соласно web.xml запрос должен пойти на com.test.sel

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns=”http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee”
xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance”
version=”2.4”
xsi:schemaLocation=”http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd”
>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>Sel</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.test.sel</servlet-class>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Sel</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/select.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**sel.java**

```
package com.test;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
public class sel extends HttpServlet {

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("<h1>Look around</h1>");
String c = request.getParameter("type");
out.println("<br>There are " + c + " cats, who're going to jump on you");
}

}
```

Как исправить?

p.s. tomcat рестарстил

Comment: то есть за вас надо локализовать проблему? кидайте сюда лог и скрин структуры (ибо по вашей ссылке все равно бесполезная инфа, конечно, если вообще кому-то захочется там ползать)
web.xml тоже можете запостить.
sel ведь Сервлет? и не надо так называть классы в Java (с маленькой буквы, и если честно не понятно по названию что там вообще)

Comment: @rasmisha я вроде и так в нормальном виде предлагаю. До лога добраться можно в 2 клика. Про скрин структуры - где его достать? Я не в ide. Вообщем в нормальном виде я оформил, не zip же даю. По dropbox папкам в онлайне тоже лазит удобно, я бы чужой вопрос пролазил.

Comment: в неудобном вы виде дали. суть в том, что завтра на дропбоксе может ничего не оказаться и ответ может оказаться бесполезным. Да и в любом случае чем поможет ваша структура? вы реально хоть класс sel скиньте (в виде кода, а не ссылок). 

p.s. а кому нужны эти ваши 2 клика? только вам

Comment: > на дропбоксе может ничего не оказаться

Так я же своей папкой управляю, значит я и решаю - удалять или нет. А удалять я не буду. 

> Да и в любом случае чем поможет ваша структура? вы реально хоть класс sel скиньте (в виде кода, а не ссылок)

Думаю 404 из-за неправильной настройки, а не кода, тем ни менее скину

Comment: может doGet(...) переопределить? Хотя не уверен, что поможет

Comment: нет, там 100% post будет

Comment: И при чем тут ``plain old java`` в названии? Это обыкновенный сервлет, а не аннотированный POJO.

Comment: @Nofate сорри, просто ещё до конца не разобрался что есть что. p.s. что в pojo последняя буква значит?

Comment: это вы сегодня не будете удалять с дропбокса, а завтра будете.

Comment: @danpetruk, [POJO](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POJO) - Plain Old Java Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему `classes` и `lib` вне `WEB-INF` лежат? Они не попадают в classpath из-за этого.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе согласен с Nofate, кроме замечания по поводу classpath(при чем тут это?)... а так насколько помню tomcat начинает по умолчанию искать в папке WEB-INF(так вроде в спецификациях прописано) т.е. туда и стоит положить папку classes(кстати помещая сервлет в WEB-INF вы защищаете его от "прямого" запроса и контролируете доступ к нему). Если есть желание "поизгаляться" попробуйте по другому прописать путь к сервлету в web.xml.
 Папку lib не обязательно класть в lib, так-же не обязательно класть туда servlet-api.jar(хотя в принципе это вопрос deploying app).

Comment: Все что Nofate хотел сказать - это кратко пересказать спеку:

    The Web application class loader must load classes from the WEB-INF/classes directory ﬁrst, and then from library JARs in the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: А classpath при чем?

Comment: Соглашусь, не совсем корректно выразился. Я имел в виду не CLASSPATH как таковой, а в широком смысле путь по которому контейнер ищет классы.

Comment: Тогда полностью с Вами согласен.